# How to find the sum of squares more efficiently?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, while-loop

Homework involves making a function that would check if a number is the sum of  two squares. I got a function to work but it is a very brute way of doing it and it takes a lot longer for larger integers to run through it. Is there anything that I can do to make it work more efficiently for larger numbers? Something to keep note of is that the function has to return the max tuple so for example given the integer `50` instead of the function returning `(5,5)`, I'd like it to return `(7,1)`
Here's the function:

```
def sum_of_squares(n) : 
  i = 1 

  while i * i <= n : 
      j = 1

      while(j * j <= n) : 

          while (i * i + j * j == n) : 

              return (j,i)

          j = j + 1
      i = i + 1
```

Comment: [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/787321/how-to-determine-whether-a-number-can-be-written-as-a-sum-of-two-squares) probably can help you (also there is [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_two_squares_theorem))

Answer (score 1):

There is a very elegant approach based on memoization, so pretty much dynamic programming. The time complexity is O(sqrt(n)).

```py
from math import sqrt, ceil
def sum_square(n): 

    s = set()
    results = []
    for i in range(ceil(sqrt(n))):

        i_square = i * i
        s.add(i_square)  # remember square value 

        if (n - i_square) in s:
            results.append((i, sqrt(n - i_square)))
            #print(f"{sqrt(n - i_square)}^2 + {i}^2") 
            #return True
    #return False
    return results[-1] if results else None

n = 169
print(sum_square(n))
```

Comment: instead of checking `i * i > n` on each iteration we can compute `ceil(sqrt(n))` and iterate over it

Comment: This does not give me the max tuple, for example when I put 50 in as a case, it returns (5,5) instead of (7,1)

Comment: @Azat: Thanks, I edited my answer. @piethon: I'm not completely sure what you mean by max tuple, but the function now returns the solution with the largest `i`.  Still O(srqt(n)), though.

Comment: @piethon same as what sammy has written. You could have referred to the link here as well. This is a pretty basic problem. [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-whether-number-can-represented-sum-two-squares/)

Answer (score 0):

A direct and short-circuited approach follows:

```
import math


def decompose_squares(n):
    i = int(math.floor(math.sqrt(n)))
    i2 = i * i
    while i2 >= n:
        i -= 1
        i2 = i * i
    j2 = 1
    while j2 <= i2:
        j = int(math.sqrt(n - i2))
        j2 = j * j
        if i2 + j2 == n:
            return i, j
        i -= 1
        i2 = i * i


print(decompose_squares(50))
# (7, 1)

print([[n, decompose_squares(n)] for n in range(1, 50) if decompose_squares(n)])
# [[2, (1, 1)], [5, (2, 1)], [8, (2, 2)], [10, (3, 1)], [13, (3, 2)], [17, (4, 1)], [18, (3, 3)], [20, (4, 2)], [25, (4, 3)], [26, (5, 1)], [29, (5, 2)], [32, (4, 4)], [34, (5, 3)], [37, (6, 1)], [40, (6, 2)], [41, (5, 4)], [45, (6, 3)]]
```

This is based on the idea that given a candidate `i` we can compute the corresponding `j` and if `i` gets smaller than the last `j` we can conclude that `n` cannot be decomposed.
Since we want the decomposition with the largest `i`, with start with the largest possible `i`.

This is faster than the memoized version because it only computes the one (and not all) couples satisfying the `i ** 2 + j ** 2 == n` relation.

---

## EDIT

Just to give you an idea on the expected speed-up, please consider the following benchmark results:

```
import math

def sum_square(n):
    s = set()
    results = []
    for i in range(1, math.ceil(math.sqrt(n))):
        i_square = i * i
        s.add(i_square)  # remember square value 
        if (n - i_square) in s:
            results.append((i, math.sqrt(n - i_square)))
    return results[-1] if results else None


funcs = sum_square, decompose_squares
for func in funcs:
    print()
    same_result = (
        [funcs[0](n) for n in range(1, 1000) if funcs[0](n)]
        == [func(n) for n in range(1, 1000) if func(n)])
    print(f'{func.__name__}()  {same_result}')
    %timeit [func(n) for n in range(1, 1000) if func(n)]

# sum_square()  True
# 100 loops, best of 3: 5.2 ms per loop

# decompose_squares()  True
# 100 loops, best of 3: 2.81 ms per loop
```